# USB Hub project

Tags: usb-device

I have a D-Link 7 port USB 2.0 hub model DUB-H7

The hub has a AC power supply that came with it, 5v 3amp output.

Problem, the hub will not supply 5v power to the 7 ports unless it is connected to a PC that is powered up and running an OS, regardless if the AC adapter is connected or not. I belive this is by design.

What I want to do is use this in a automobile to power some of my usb devices, but not have it connected to a PC. I have a power inverter in the vehicle to supply the 110v for the d-link ac power supply.

Not knowing how D-link designed the circuit board, it there some fundamental usb hub design that causes this behavior.

[I did some reading on this page](http://pinouts.ru/Slots/USB_pinout.shtml), but know just enough about USB electronics to get into trouble and let some smoke out, is there a way to make a usb dongle to fool the d-link into believing it is connected to a PC?

Comment: What's a USB hub without being connected to a host? A USB charger? There are probably easier ways to make a USB charger than using a USB hub. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MJAPv3iIAc

Comment: Just working with what I have on hand, yes a usb charger. It has a nice enclosure, in the end I guess I could gut it and make my own board to fit or modify the one that is in it, but more interested in fooling this one into working by making a usb dongle if possible.

Comment: Try connecting multiple hubs to each other... you'll get some interesting results :p

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you simple supply 5V with a suitable current limit to the ground and power lines of your USB gadet. A simple 7805 will do fine.  There are numerous designs and commercial gadgets (battery powered, wall-wart powered, cigarette plug powered, some even solar panel powered - I doubt they are effective) that do something like this this. Some links:

- [2 cell version](http://www.instructables.com/id/MintyBoost!---Small-battery-powered-USB-charger/)
- very ugly: [9V battery + zener](http://hackaday.com/2005/01/20/how-to-make-a-usb-battery/)
- [commercial 4 cell](http://www.bixnet.com/usbbaboxc4aa.html), will probably output 6V, yuk!
- [9V battery + 7805](http://www.instructables.com/id/Portable-USB-Charger-Version-2.0/)
- [cigarette plug + 7805](http://www.modd3d.com/articles/item/build-a-usb-car-charger)

Comment: Wouter, you're probably a good guy, but how I would love to see that links in-line! :-). Ah, what the heck, I'll do it myself.

Comment: i've done 7805 version for myself, by putting through 0.5A it's near it's limits and is hot as hell. I'm not sure about voltage spikes from generator - i was doing it for myself strictly for engine-off mode. What overvoltage protection could be added to a plot?

Comment: Thanks, more interested in making a usb dongle to make what I have on hand work. Thanks for the alternative idea's though, but would need 5 or more usb ports for charging/operation purposes and be able to power from my 110v inverter or +12v car battery.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with adding pull up resistors on the data lines, but have no clue what that means.

Comment: @Moab: I think what you want is *much* more work, but its your party... I guess there will be a connection between the hub chip and the pass P-FETs, you could cut that and connect it to ground, or even short the FETs with 1A polyfuses.

Comment: @steven: thanks, I'll try to remember the syntax. I once spend some toem to figure it out, could not find it quickly enough for my taste, so I gave up. Now I can simply open the edit fo my post :)

Comment: @Wouter - Or any other question or answer. Experience learns that it can be difficult to find a certain answer back, even if it's your own. Link text between [], followed by link between (). Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This CAN be done.  Turns out that the D-Link uses the reference design for the chipset it uses.  The guys I used to work with went in and modified these by cutting a jumper and the hub was then powered without host being connected.

You can see that they guys built a 49 port hub for me, with all 49 ports being able to charge without computer.

https://blogs.oracle.com/eric/entry/49_port_usb_hub_49

Sorry I can't provide you with the exact jumper, but if you can find someone who can open it up for you and cut a jumper, I dont think there are that many inside.